# Floating separate containers left/right to each other

Tags: html, css, css-float, containers

I have 5 containers:

```
<div class="wrapper">
 <div id="container-1"></div>
 <div id="container-2"></div>
 <div id="container-3"></div>
 <div id="container-4"></div>
 <div id="container-5"></div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to float the first 3 containers to the left, and the last 2 to the right (starting next to the first one floated left, on top)

currently I only achieved to float the first 3 to the left, and the last 2 to the right, but starting next to the last, floated left container and not to the top one.

Fiddle:

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.left,
.right {
  width: 40%;
  height: 100px;
  float: left;
  clear: left;
  background: red;
  margin: 5px;
}

.right {
  float: right;
  clear: right;
  background: green;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>div's are dynamic so left/right divs will be added, so unable to fixed position them in html</li>
</ul>
<div class="left"></div>
<div class="left"></div>
<div class="right"></div>
<div class="left"></div>
<div class="right"></div>
<div class="left"></div>
```

Expected result should be e.g.

```
1 - 3
2 - 5
4 - /
6
```

Comment: In html you used id selector and in css you write class selector.. how it work?

Comment: Edited it, mistake here because I just retyped it :) but selectors are OK

Comment: It was only 5 container or more?

Comment: The number of containers are dynamic based on content that is added to the site

Comment: can you please share your full markup

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Kemagezien/p89xfrm3/8/

Answer (score 3):

You can used `Flexbox` to ordering the elements

```css
.wrapper {
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
#container-1, #container-2, #container-3, #container-4, #container-5{
 float:left;
 width: 50%; 
}
#container-1 {
  order:1;
}
#container-4 {
  order:2;
}
#container-2 {
  order:3;
}
#container-3 {
  order:5;
}
#container-5 {
  order:4;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="container-1">container 1</div>
  <div id="container-2">container 2</div>
  <div id="container-3">container 3</div>
  <div id="container-4">container 4</div>
  <div id="container-5">container 5</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey, great start but as my divs are going to be dynamic using order won't be the best solution. => https://jsfiddle.net/Kemagezien/p89xfrm3/

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

```css
  html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position:relative;
}

.left,
.right {
  width: 40%;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 5px;

}

.left{
   float: left;
  clear: left;
  background: red;
}

 .right ~ .right{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  right:0;
}
.right {
  background: green;
  text-align: right;
  float:right;
}
```

```html
<div class="left"></div>
<div class="left"></div>
<div class="right"></div>
<div class="left"></div>
<div class="right"></div>
<div class="left"></div>
```

**EDIT 2**

```css
      html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.left,
.right {
  width: 40%;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 5px;

}

.left{
   float: left;
  clear: left;
  background: red;
}

.right {
  background: green;
  text-align: right;
  float:right;
}
```

```html
<div class="left"></div>
<div class="right"></div>
<div class="right"></div>
<div class="left"></div>
<div class="left"></div>
<div class="left"></div>
```

Comment: Hi, You added a container-div around it (classes left and right). Im not able to change/add/remove code to the one I have :)

Comment: hmm okey, then you have to force it to be there i guess, but it won't be pretty, with something like position: relative; bottom: (some px) . Why can't you change it ?

Comment: Working with other dev-people, they decide. Im trying to achieve it with flexbox at but seems the same problem. https://jsfiddle.net/Kemagezien/zem6js03/1/

Comment: @Kemagezien look at Manish Patel answer, i think its what you look for then :)

Comment: Alright, but if I add more "right"-divs they all go to top:0 and overflow eachother

This is fixed by keep adding ~ .right but ... hmmm...

Comment: @Kemagezien can you change the order, like my edit 2 ?

Answer (score 0):

I think that I might have found a solution to this issue. Hope I'm not too late.

Here's the new code:

HTML ( Added a few more elements to test it out )

```
<ul>
  <li>div's are dynamic so left/right divs will be added, so unable to fixed position them in html</li>
</ul>
<div class="left"></div>
<div class="left"></div>
<div class="right"></div>
<div class="left"></div>
<div class="right"></div>
<div class="left"></div>
<div class="right"></div>
<div class="left"></div>
<div class="right"></div>
<div class="left"></div>
```

CSS:

```
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.left,
.right {
  width: 40%;
  height: 100px;
  float: left;
  clear: left;
  background: red;
  margin: 5px;
}

.right {
  float: right;
  clear: right;
  background: green;
  text-align: right;
  position: relative; 
  top: -110px; 
}
```

Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xw456o6c/1/